# Solve a system of linear congruences

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this system:

$$ \begin{align}
    a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + \ldots + a_{1n} x_n &= b_1 \mod p \\
    a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 + \ldots + a_{2n} x_n &= b_2 \mod p \\
    \vdots \\
    a_{n1} x_1 + a_{n2} x_2 + \ldots + a_{nn} x_n &= b_n \mod p \\
\end{align} $$

Can I solve it using ordinary Gaussian elimination? It seems to be incorrect to multiply a row by a constant, and then add or subtract this row with another, right?

If Gaussian elimination can't be applied here, then what other technique can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When p is a prime number, the integers modulo p still form a field (as the rationals and the reals do).

The Gaussian elimination works over any field, so in this case as well. Just be sure that you understand how to invert elements mod p and how to test for zero mod p.

For general p (that is, p is not a prime number), you can still make something similar to Gaussian elimination. Just bring your coefficient matrix into Smith normal form over the integers, which is a diagonal matrix. This makes solving the resulting equations mod p trivial.

The Smith normal form is described here, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form.

The problem is even solvable in case the modulus on the right hand side is not the same for each equation. Given
$$
a_{11} x_1 + \dots + a_{1m} x_m = b_1 \pmod {p_1} \\
\vdots\\
a_{n1} x_1 + \dots + a_{nm} x_m = b_n \pmod {p_n},
$$
rewrite the system as
$$
a_{11} x_1 + \dots + a_{1m} x_m + p_1 y = b_1 \\
\vdots\\
a_{n1} x_1 + \dots + a_{nm} x_m + p_n y = b_n,
$$
which is in the variables $x_1, \dots, x_n, y$. Solve this system over the integers (using Smith normal form). Finally project the resulting solutions $(x_1, \dots, x_n, y)$ to $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't understand why should **p** be prime to **form a field**, what does it mean?

Comment: A commutative ring is an algebraic structure where you can do addition and multiplication and where those operations obey the usual rules, e.g. the commutativity laws and the distributivity law. Examples of rings are the integers, the reals and the integers modulo n. A field is a special type of a commutative ring, namely where an element in multiplicatively invertible if and only if it is non-zero. This is true for the rationals or the reals where you are allowed to divide by an element if and only if it is non-zero, so both for a field... (to be continued)

Comment: ... It is not true for the integers, e.g. 2 can not be inverted in the integers as there is no integer x with 2 * x = 1. The integers mod n usually do not form a field either: E.g. consider the case n = 6. Then 2 * 3 = 0 mod n. Therefore, neither 2 nor 3 can possess an inverse although both are zero. For n a prime number p, however, the integers mod p do form a field. Take p = 5, for example. A multiplicative inverse for, say, 2 is given by 3 because 2 * 3 = 1 mod 5.

Comment: ... The reason for this is the Euclidean algorithm. If a is non-zero mod p, this means that p does not divide a, that is the gcd of a and p is 1. The Euclidean algorithm (performed in the integers) yield integers s and t such that 1 = s a + t p. It follows that s is a multiplicative inverse for a mod p.

Comment: Thank you so much, although it'll take some efforts for to digest your explanation, ;-). By **form a field**, you mean there indeed are solutions for a problem?

Comment: Your problem is always algorithmically solvable. It is just easier to solve in case p a prime number because in these cases, the usual Gaussian elimination suffices. By **forming a field** I mean that the ring of the integers mod p (that is the integers mod p together with their addition and multiplication operations) behave a bit better than in the general case, namely that division works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, you're doing me a big favor.

Comment: No problem, mathematics is my area of work. Feel free to ask in case you have further questions.

Comment: **Smith normal form** works over *PIDs*, if $p$ is not a prime, then $integer \pmod p$ doesn't form a PID, then why Smith normal form still works here if $p$ is not prime?

Comment: You turn the left hand side into Smith normal form over the integers, not mod p. The resulting equations will look like a x = b mod p after the left hand side has been diagonalized. The equations are easily solvable. I'll also complement my answer to include the case of more than one modulus.

Comment: very clear, ;-)